# How to match cell to lookup table?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am trying to set up an expense tracker. I copy-paste my credit card transactions directly in Google Sheets. I want to categorize them into say grocery, restaurant, gas, movies, etc. I want to do this using some sort of lookup table which I can keep adding to in the future.

The lookup table could look something like:

```
A          B
cafe       restaurant
cuisine    restaurant
restaurant restuarant
gas        gas
amc        movies
safeway    grocery
costco     grocery
```

Now, the copy-paste from my credit card statement looks something like this:

```
A                   B       
AMC20 BILL          12      
RRCAFE              20      
COSTCOPAYMNET       80      
ARCOGAS             30      
THE CUISINE BLOCK   20
```

The final outcome that I want is this:

```
A                   B       C
AMC20 BILL          12      movies
RRCAFE              20      restaurant
COSTCOPAYMNET       80      grocery
ARCOGAS             30      gas
THE CUISINE BLOCK   20      restaurant
```

I tried looking at `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` but couldn't figure out a way to do this reverse lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D1:D), 
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(D1:D), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A)), A:B, 2, 0), ))
```

[image: 0]